# Retrieve arguments in Service - Symfony

Tags: symfony

I want to understand service in symfony

I have read http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container

and I want to try to create my service

in my config.yml

```
services:
    my_service:
        class:        Acme\FooBundle\myService
        arguments:    ['my_param']
```

in My controller

```
public function serviceAction(){
        $Myservice = $this->get('my_service');
        return array();
    }
```

in My Class /service

```
class myService{

    public function __construct() {
        echo "In BaseClass constructor\n";
    }

}
```

The Question is:
How can I Retrive my_param in my Class service? 
I want to retrieve `arguments:    ['my_param']`

Comment: you should consider renaming your service class. It is a common convention to start your class names with a capital letter. However, if this is an existing project, stick to the existing naming.

Answer (score 5):

Arguments are being passed to your service constructor as parameters:

```
class myService{

    private $my_param;

    public function __construct($param) {
        $this->my_param = $param;
        echo $this->my_param;
        echo "In BaseClass constructor\n";
    }

}
```